# Is it possible to do string concatenation in a ColdFusion Query of Queries?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I'm familiar with this sort of syntax in SQL Server, to concatenate strings in my result set:

```
SELECT 'foo' + bar AS SomeCol
FROM SomeTable
```

I would like to do something similar inside a ColdFusion Query of Queries:

```
<cfquery name="qOptimize" dbtype="query">
    select 
        image_id AS imageId,
        '#variables.img_root#' + image_id + '.' + image_ext AS fullImage,
        '#variables.img_root#' + image_id + 't.' + image_ext AS thumbnailImage,
    from qLookup
    order by imageId asc
</cfquery>
```

This is part of a service consumed by a Flex application, so I'm optimizing the result of a stored procedure used elsewhere in the application before returning to the client -- stripping out unused columns, and compiling image URLs from some dynamic path information.

I could write a new stored procedure that takes the image root as a parameter and does all of this, **and I probably *will* for performance reasons**, but the question is still nagging me. I haven't found a syntax that works yet, so I wonder if it's possible.

When I try the above, I get the following error:

> **Query Of Queries syntax error.**
>   Encountered "from. Incorrect Select List, Incorrect select column,

Has anyone done this? Is it possible, perhaps with another syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I think the problem is that image_id is most likely a numeric value. If you cast it as an varchar then it should be fine.

```
<cfquery name="qOptimize" dbtype="query">
    select 
        image_id AS imageId,
        '#variables.img_root#' + cast(image_id as varchar) + '.' + image_ext AS fullImage,
        '#variables.img_root#' + cast(image_id as varchar) + 't.' + image_ext AS thumbnailImage
    from qLookup
    order by imageId asc
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I ran into this when I converted it to a stored procedure, but thanks.

Comment: But how to concat same string if postgres database in used

Comment: By using the ANSI-standard concatenation operator `||`

Answer (score 5):

I think the error you mention is due to the comma at the last concatenation, at the end of thumbnailImage.

Just my $0.002

Comment: Agree 100%. If the sample code was the actual code used, the last comma was the deal breaker. Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

or even when you need the concatenate not on coldfusion level but in the query itself:

in my example, I have already a query result object which I want to dig into with query of queries. the query resul tobject has 10 columns of data and 1000 rows, the column names are c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, ...

```
    <cfset dbzeilerest = "2 4 - 3"><!--- beg qoq to concatenate those columns --->
    <cfset sqlcodehere = "(">
    <cfloop list="#dbzeilerest#" delimiters="," index="t">
        <cfif val(t) GT 0>
            <cfset sqlcodehere = sqlcodehere & "C" & val(t) & " || ">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset sqlcodehere = sqlcodehere & "'" & t & "' || ">
        </cfif>
    <!--- concat in coldfusion sql qoq: 
          ( C2 || ' ' || C4 || ' ' || '-' || ' ' || C3 ) as combii --->
    </cfloop>
    <cfset sqlcodehere = sqlcodehere & " '') as combii">
    <cfquery name="dbtexttemp2" dbtype="query">
    SELECT DISTINCT #PreserveSingleQuotes(sqlcodehere )# FROM dbtexttemplistequery
    </cfquery>
```

Comment: That sounds like a very specialized case. Generally it is better to avoid dynamic sql when possible, because it can expose "database" queries to sql injection. Not to mention it is often harder for a db to optimize.